# Importing a module but the interpreter is not recognizing the function in that module python

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I am importing a tokenize module to my project.  Tokenize imports regexp.py

When I try to call a function located in regexp.py  like that in my program

```
m = tokenize.regexp_tokenize(itemToString.lower(), n)
```

I get an error 'module' object has no attribute 'regexp_tokenize'.

regexp_tokenize is a function in regexp.py.

Any idea what could be the problem?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You said yourself that you imported tokenize, not regexp. If `regexp_tokenize` is in regexp, you would need to import regexp yourself.

You *could* access it via `tokenzie.regexp.regexp_tokenize`, but that's not usual practice.

Comment: I agree with you, it is strange.  I now got this error message:

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'regexp'.

Comment: The problem is that I am I didn't know that there is a new tokenize module in python 2.7. So every time I was importing tokenize , I was actually calling the system module not my tokenize module.  Thanks a lot.